# Dependency Version Requirement Specification for management pom import

Tags: maven, version, dependency-management

It's possible to specify a requirement version for dependency ( https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification )

I try to limit version for import pom artifact into dependency management like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                             xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                            <version>(,1.5.10.RELEASE]</version>
                            <type>pom</type>
                            <scope>import</scope>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

But I got this error :

> Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:(,1.5.10.RELEASE] in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 14, column 16

How to fix max version for `pom` artifact in `import` scope ?

Comment: simply cause you can't use version ranges in dependencyManagement. Furthermore I can't recommend to use them. Simply define the version for spring boot fix and that's it...Apart from that is the question why not defining it as parent as suggested by the spring boot documentation? Do you have special reasons?

Comment: @khmargaise Thanks for the suggestion but I have already a parent (in the real world) that why I can define Spring boot as parent.

Comment: Than you have simply to use the import scope as already shown in your example without the version range...

Comment: I use range because we are not compatible with version 2.X

Comment: So simply set version `1.5.10.RELEASE` and that's it...and update if you wish...

Comment: This artifact is require by some other artifact, they can choose version 2.X. 
If I well understand the range `(,1.5.10.RELEASE]`  throw error on maven cycle life.